# Laptop self charge cable?

Tags: electricity, energy-conservation

Ok this is a really silly question, but I was really curious as to why this wouldnt work. I'm just starting my electricity and magnetism course, so I really dont know much about electricity. I know this is not possible, but why?
[image]

Comment: The name "The Hedgehog From Hell Industries" clearly indicates that this is a cheap prank.

Comment: Well I know, but it still got me thinking..

Comment: I don't think that this question belongs here.

Comment: It is too basic so I close it (hopefully) to prevent downvotes, yet I believe it should stay here as a reference, especially with sb1's answer.

Comment: Ever heard from "Baron Münchhausen"? He pulled himself out of a swamp gripping his own hair. In earnest: there are some gadgets offerd to be fed by the USB-connector, which are nonsense, because the USB will feed .5 Amp maximum. I think this cabe is a joke on this or the silliness of certain "cable buyers" in general.

Comment: @Georg This story was a base for "boostrap" in a meaning of self-initiation in CS (booting computer is short for bootstrapping it) and extracting seemingly non-reachable parameters from data in statistics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, but your self charging laptop can not work since it will violate the second law of thermodynamics. A computer processes information and during computation it generates heat. This heat is dissipated through the cooling system. You need continuous supply of usable energy from an external source to run the laptop.

In general, the second law of thermodynamics asserts that it is impossible to create a perpetual motion machine of the second kind. All real machines have efficiency less than 100% which means output power is less than input power. The difference is lost/ wasted as heat or other useless forms of energy. You must have noticed your laptop's temperature is high and making noisy sound during a heavy computation.

I hope you got the point.

Comment: Hi sb1, don't you primarily need the first law of thermodynamics, the conservation of energy here? ;-)

Comment: abosolutely lubos ;-) but i thought, it would be trivial to mention this ;-)

Comment: Although, I suppose the first law by itself would allow you to charge your computer using its own USB port as long as the computer didn't do anything else ;-) but then it wouldn't really be a computer, of course.

Comment: One does not need any thoughts on "information" here. The whole thing can be wieved as a accumulator of, say 12 Volt, a step-down stage making 5 Volts from those 12 Volts with an efficency of  less than 100 % and then a feedback cable from 5Volt USB to the charger input which requires a bit above 12 Volt. (I assumed the laptop has a 12 Volt accumulator, maybe those laptops have 15 Volt, but this does not change the nonsensicality)